# What's the difference between [Test] (optional [Values]) versus [TestCase] (optional ExpectedResult)?

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, nunit

The actual question is at the bottom. I've tried to make the post as short as possible already and I hope that I've managed to straighten most of the unclear parts of the issue.

According to the docs, we have in nUnit (among other attributes)

- [Test](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Attribute)
- [Values](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Values-Attribute)
- [TestCase](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCase-Attribute)

I've been reading in the docs and using all all the above since long time so I'm well familiar with how they behave. However, one thought has always bugged me and by now, I'm embarrassed to ask.

```
public int Output(int input) { return input + 1; }
```

The way we could set up test for a simple method like the one above, I can think of four approaches. I've seen most of them pretty much everywhere but I can't really tell if those are different flavors leading to the same under-the-hood functionality or if there's a technical difference that I'm simply not aware of.

For instance - perhaps #2 can be parallellized whereas the other can't (it's just a dummy example to show that there might be magic that we're not aware of).

Test attribute only

```
[Test]
public void OutputIsWorking()
{
  List<int> inputs = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };
  for(int i = 0; i < inputs.Count; i++)
    Assert.That(inputs[i] + 1, Is.EqualTo(Output(input)));
}
```

Test and Values attributes combined

```
[Test]
public void OutputIsGreat([Values(1,2,3)] int input)
{
  int output = Output(input);
  Assert.That(input + 1, Is.EqualTo(output));
}
```

TestCase attribute only

```
[TestCase(1, 2)]
[TestCase(2, 3)]
[TestCase(3, 4)]
public void DivideTest(int input, int expectation)
{
  int output = Output(input);
  Assert.That(output, Is.EqualTo(expectation));
}
```

TestCase and ExpectedResult attributes combined

```
[TestCase(1, ExpectedResult = 2)]
[TestCase(2, ExpectedResult = 3)]
[TestCase(3, ExpectedResult = 4)]
public void DivideTest(int input)
{
  return Output(input);
}
```

So, the question is if those approaches differ on a technical level or if it's just whatever the code is most fond of at the moment. We prefer to lower the number of choices a developer needs to make and providing such a wide range of equivalents seems redundant and confusing.

If they differ, then I'd like to know how. I haven't found that in the docs. If they don't differ, then I'm curious why. Are we talking about "let people decide what they like" or rather "this is a legacy thing that can't be removed"?

Comment: A bit off-topic I guess, but I get worried when I read "We prefer to lower the number of choices a developer needs to make." 

The world is complex and there are choices to be made for sure. The NUnit team has tried very hard to limit - even eliminate - unnecessary choices. __We are__ developers. If your use of "We" indicates you are not one, then please stop trying to "limit the choices" of the developers. If you are one and it was just a manner of speaking, I apologize in advance.

Comment: @Charlie Very interesting point. Let me elaborate on what I meant as I'm sure we agree on the principle. Firstly - I **am** a developer. Been since decades. Now, what I mean is that **I, as a developer,** like to be given a set of options and then decide using my skills, experience, education and intelligence the optimal one. Then, I'll apply it. If there's a standard or proven method to e.g. compute a convex hull, I want to use **it** and since I know, in such case, that the optimal approach is **that one**, I don't have to make any choices. I just apply what's already known to be the best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some subtle differences.

- Test cases count

  In the first example (`Test` attribute only), you're writing a single test case. If the test fails on input `2`, the whole test will fail, and input `3` will *not* be tested at all.

  In all the other examples, you're writing *separate test cases*, so even if `2` fails, NUnit will still test *all* the remaining cases, and show then as such in the test report.

  You can also opt-in to [parallel test execution](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute) on NUnit 3 when you have several test cases. If you use a different runner such as NCrunch you can also get parallelism easily by using separate test cases.
- Combinatorial

  When you're using `ValuesAttribute`, and you have several parameters, NUnit will execute all possible combinations of input values as separate tests. By using `TestCaseAttribute`, you'd have to write all the inputs yourself.

  You can use [`CombinatorialAttribute`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Combinatorial-Attribute) to mark this explicitly, or use [`PairwiseAttribute`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Pairwise-Attribute) or [`SequentialAttribute`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Sequential-Attribute) for a different approach.

Other differences are mostly just a matter of preference.

Using `ExpectedResult` frees you from having to write an assert (it's implicitly inserted by NUnit for you), and having to write less code is arguably a good thing. I wouldn't write the "`TestCase` attribute only" example myself, I'd rather use the `ExpectedResult` feature for this, as I think it's more readable this way (the output parameter stands out).

I'd favor `TestCase` over `Values` when I *do not* want the combinatorial behavior, but it's just a matter of style when you have a single parameter. With several input parameters, you'll probably need both approaches anyway.